# Javascript break/return function within function

Tags: javascript

I have always been confused about the best way to handle this. The method I have been using in the past works but it seems like there has to be a better way.

Below I have a section of code that I'm wanting to return `item` for the function `getData`. Problem is in the example below it's returning for the `forEach` function not the `getData` function.

```
function getData() {
    var array = ["element1","element2"];
    array.forEach(function (item) {
        if (item == "element2") {
            return item;
        }
    }); 
}
```

I have been doing something like this to overcome this.

```
function getData() {
    var array = ["element1","element2"];
    var returnValue;
    array.forEach(function (item) {
        if (item == "element2") {
            returnValue = item;
        }
    });
    if (returnValue) {
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to handle this? Seems like those extra 4 lines of code just create confusion and clutter in my code.

Comment: [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: If you just used a for loop, you could just return with no problem. Failing that, you pretty much have to do something like the above.

Comment: You could simplify by removing the `if` statement at the end though. If returnValue hasn't been set, it would be `undefined`, so would return undefined--just the same as when the if fails; the function would return `undefined` anyway.

Comment: This is a main disadvantage of using `.forEach()` to iterate your array.  Use a regular `for` loop and you can then directly return from your function with no extra code.  Or, if all you're doing in the iteration is just looking for a value, then just use `.indexOf()` and let it iterate the array for you.

Comment: It's not just a disadvantage of `forEach`, it's a disadvantage of using closures in general.

Comment: Listen to zerkms, `indexOf` is your best choice. A `for()` loop may not be as performant as that, and nobody can tell what speedups will be possible in future implementations of those functions. In some special fortuitous cases you may even have hash buckets underneath...

Comment: @jfriend00, no the main problem here is that he uses `forEach()` for this task. It's the wrong tool. The right tool would probably be `find()` or `reduce()`, depending on the real use-case, since this code is just an example.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

> The `some()` method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

```
function getData() {
    var array = ["element1","element2"];
    var returnValue;
    array.some(function (item) {
        if (item == "element2") {
            returnValue = item;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return returnValue;
}
```

Or, if you use ES6, use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

> The **`find()`** method returns a `value` in the array, if an element in the array satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is [`returned`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined).

```
function getData() {
    var array = ["element1","element2"];
    return array.find(item => item == "element2");
}
```

Comment: Same problem, but that would be a tad more efficient, I agree.

Comment: @Whothehellisthat what do you mean by "problem"?

Comment: @Nina Scholz: if they use ES2015 they may gain some more with arrow functions.

Comment: You have to add code, whether you're using .forEach or .some. I made that comment before the ES6 addition, so I wasn't talking about that.

Comment: Though I think the OP was looking for a better way to do it syntactically, not necessarily saving on bytes or optimising.

Comment: OP: "Seems like those extra 4 lines of code just create confusion and clutter in my code." Those extra lines are still there when using .some(). Better with .find(), though it's up to him if he wants to use ES6 or not. That's fine.

Comment: @Whothehellisthat is correct. I'm looking for a way to make it more clean and readable. For loops work good but overall I prefer the syntax of forEach better and it's easier to make your code readable with forEach. I'm just looking for a way to return something to the function about something else. forEach was just a common example. But could be used in many other cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can readily do this with `Array#indexOf`:

```
function getData() {
    var array = ["element1","element2"];
    var index = array.indexOf("element2");
    return index === -1 ? null : array[index];
}
```

In that case, it works because what you're looking for is an `===` match for what you have. The more general case is a case for `Array#find`, which is an ES2015 thing but you can easily [shim/polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill) it for ES5 and below:

```
function getData() {
    var array = ["element1","element2"];
    return array.find(function (item) {
        return item == "element2";
    }); 
}
```

...which lets you specify the match based on a more complex condition.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use indexOf:

```
return array[array.indexOf("element2")];
```

If it doesn't find the value, the index will be -1. And index -1 of any array will be `undefined`.